# NPSQL Where Clause in .Net Core

Tags: .net, postgresql

I am trying to write an npsql command in .net with Where clause like below;

```
string query =("SELECT start::timestamp FROM" + table+ " WHERE name= "+name)

NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(query, connection);
NpgsqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

But, it gives me syntax error, what do I need to write for where clause?

Comment: You're probably going to need to give us what the syntax error is.

Answer (score 1):

`... FROM" + table+ ...` there should be a space between `FROM` and the table name in the query. But your string concatenation won't generate that.

And `name` is probably a string. String literals need to be enclosed in single quotes in SQL. I strongly recommend to rework the code and use parameterized queries but if you insist on using pure string concatenation try:

```
...
string query = "SELECT start::timestamp FROM " + table + " WHERE name = '" + name + "'";
...
```